# What is the syntax to skip rows while selecting data for chart in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

***Edit: Moved the data around to make it more clear for myself and realized my question was incorrect as well as not thorough enough.***

I am attempting to pass over two rows while selecting data for a chart in Excel. I need to select from column J-N, but from K-N, I need to skip rows 2-3. F is the X-axis. How do you formulate in Excel that you want all of column J, and all of column K-N except rows 2-3?

```
=Sheet1!$F$1:$F$113,Sheet1!$J$1:$N$113
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this basic macro...it will copy Col J, then hide Rows 2 & 3 and copy cols K:N visible cells only. Adjust the source and destination to suit your needs.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Columns("J").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
    Destination:=Sheet2.Range("A1")

    .Range("A2:A3").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    .Columns("K:N").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
    Destination:=Sheet2.Range("B1")
End With
```